# Proving that the set of real orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices is compact in $ M^{n \times n}( \mathbb{R})$.

Tags: matrices, compactness

Let $ M^{n \times n}( \mathbb{R})$ denote the set of $n \times n$ matrices with real coefficients and $S_O$ the set of orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices with real coefficients.

I want to prove that $S_O$ is compact in $ M^{n \times n}( \mathbb{R})$. I know this may appear to be a duplicate of other similar posts, but I have the following problem:

Most of the proofs I have come across seem to use the Heine-Borel property, meaning that one shows that $S_O$ is closed and bounded, and therefore also compact. But as far as I am aware, the Heine-Borel Theorem holds only for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I do realize that some metric spaces/vector spaces/topological spaces have the so called Heine-Borel property and the Theorem can therefore be applied, but how do I know/prove that the space $ M^{n \times n}( \mathbb{R})$  has this property?

Could it also be that I am missing out on something very obvious? To me $S_O$ is a subset of $ M^{n \times n}( \mathbb{R})$ and not $\mathbb{R}^n$, so using the Theorem does seem a little bit off to me.

I really hope someone out there has some kind of useful input regarding this dilemma.

Thanks.

Comment: $M^{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ is rather evidently $\Bbb R^{n^2}$, is it not?

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix is just a fancy way of writing  $n^2$ real numbers, from this point of view.

Comment: @Gae.S.  Yes, you're right, but consider this thought: if $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is viewed as the set of all $n^2$-tuples over $\mathbb{R}$, which is normally the case I believe, then no real $n \times n$ matrix would be element of this set, as matrices and tuples are not the same objects mathematically speaking. But of course, if a matrix is viewed as a "collection" of $n^2$ real numbers, like Robert Israel said, then I can see that $S_O$ is a subset of the euclidean space and therefore the Theorem can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

What topology/metric do you put on $M^{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ besides the obvious topology/metric given by the identification of $M^{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

If you do give it the obvious choice of a metric, then Heine-Borel theorem clearly applies.

Then since all norms a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent, for any norm, we get the Heine Borel theorem, since closed and bounded in one norm implies closed and bounded in the Euclidean norm, for which we already have the Heine Borel theorem.

Comment: I'm using the matrix norm defined by  $\left\|A\right\|:=\underset{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{x\neq 0}}{\sup}\frac{\left\|Ax\right\|}{\left\|x\right\|}$. This norm induces a suitable metric and thus also a topology.

Comment: @GreenSquid see edit.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of compactness depends directly on the topology you equip your sets with. The standard way is to equip the set of $n\times n$ matrices with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ via the obvious bijective identification of $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.